# Trying to get property 'position' of non-object

Tags: laravel

I had getting error of Trying to get property 'position' of non-object. While redirecting to another page from resume submission page.

```
public function jobcode($job_code)
{
    $jobpost = DB::table('jobposts')->where('job_code',$job_code)->first();

    return view('home.resumesubmission',compact('jobpost'));
}
```

Basic Eligibility Criteria: {{ $jobpost->position }}

```
            <hr>

            <p><strong>Job Code:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->job_code }}  </p>

            <p><strong>Job Discription:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->job_discription }}   </p>

            <p><strong>Skills Required:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->skills_required }}  </p>

            <p><strong>Eligibility:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->eligibility }}  </p>

            <p><strong>Package:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->package }}  </p>

            <p><strong>Department:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->department }}  </p>

            <p><strong>Location:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->location }}   </p>

            <p><strong>Employement Type:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->employement_type }}  </p>

            <p><strong>Note:</strong>  {{ $jobpost->detail }}  </p>

            <hr>
```

can anyone please helpme on this.

Answer (score 0):

What is in `$jobpost`? Is it array or object or null. Try to dump `$jobpost` if it's an array access it with [] instead of ->

change

```
{{ $jobpost->position }}
```

to

```
{{ $jobpost['position'] ?? 'NA' }}
```

also wrap your code in `@isset($jobpost)` 'your code' `@endisset`

Comment: the error is because of worng url routing on layout page.